# Double loop with drop table in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, drop-table

I've while loop inside while loop and both loops do some modifications of one table. I receive an error that table already exists. Below simple example of this problem. Could someone clarify why this doesn't work? I know how to bypass this problem in this particular case, nevertheless I'd like to understand where did it come from.

```
CREATE TABLE #a(
  ID int)

DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @j INT  

SET @i = 1
SET @j = 1

WHILE @i < 10
BEGIN

    SELECT  *
    INTO #b
    FROM  #a

    DROP TABLE #b

    WHILE @j < 10 BEGIN
        SELECT  *
        INTO #b
        FROM  #a

        DROP TABLE #b

        SET @j = @j + 1
    END

  SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Comment: This is a compile error because the engine does not logically process the entire batch. It sees that you are using select into #b more than once and determines this will fail. But lucky for you that happened because looping like this in sql is a really bad idea. With very few exceptions there are set based solutions that we can use that are easier to code, easier to maintain and perform better than loops.

Comment: the problem is you can only use select into #b once. to solve either truncate table or have 1 create table for #b and 2 insert statements to #b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sean Lange pointed out, you can probably do whatever your doing without loops.

You cannot have two statements in the same procedure that create a temp table with the same name. 
This is a leftover from SQL 6.5 which did not have deferred name resolution.

Instead of using `select into`, use `create table + insert`.

Instead of dropping and recreating the same table with the same schema, use `truncate table`.

[Answer by Erland Sommarskog on MSDN Social](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8c7ddea5-1021-429c-bdb2-c3a4df245320/why-am-i-getting-there-is-already-an-object-named-temptable-in-the-database-within-my-sql?forum=transactsql)

```
create table #a(ID int);
create table #b(ID int);
declare @i int;
declare @j int;
set @i = 1;
set @j = 1;
while @i < 10
  begin;
    insert into #b (id)
      select id
      from #a;

    truncate table #b;

    while @j < 10
      begin;
        insert into #b (id)
          select id
          from #a

        truncate table #b;

        set @j = @j + 1;
      end;
    set @i = @i + 1;
  end;
```